# Backbone.Marionette - Grunt Browserify - "require is not defined"

Tags: backbone.js, automation, marionette, gruntjs, browserify

I'm using [grunt-browserify](https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify) and running into two issues in particular.  The task is up and running successfully with the following config options.  The variable `jsFilesToConcat` represents all of the javascript files for a Backbone.js + Marionette.js application, the main application defintion, the front-end utility assets (e.g. Bootstrap plugins), and all JS associated with the project.  Is this the wrong approach?  The thought was to load the entire 250k JS application (and all it's dependencies) at one time.

I want to offer the disclaimer that this is new territory for me, so I think my intended use case is available with the options already available with the plugin, but I'm confused by two errors:

1) `Backbone not defined` - which means that the script is in fact loading, however, when I inspect the call stack in Chrome Dev Tools it shows only the anonymous self-invoking function.  So I'm not clear on how to pass the Backbone object to Marionette in order for it to be extended at load time.

2) `require is not defined` - error on the line where I'm declaring `var SampleApp = require('SampleApp')`.  Do I need to do something special within my grunt config, or node.js server.js config to expose the `require` function?

3) Is the javascript executing asynchronously within itself, is this part of the browserify intended behavior that I'm not properly handling?  I think since I'm wrapping alot of JS utilities in a global wrapper to protect namespacing, that's the reason some functions are not available, but I'm not clear on why that would affect `require`.

```
    // uses grunt-browserify task
    browserify: {
        developmentJs: {
            options: {
                debug: true,
                alias: ["./js/app.dev.js:SampleApp"],
            },
            src: [
                '<%= pkg.jsFilesToConcat %>'
            ],
            dest: 'public-dev/js/app.dev.js'
        }
    }
```

and then in the `index.html` of my single-page Marionette app, I have.

```
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready( function() {
            var sampleApp = require('SampleApp');
            console.log( SampleApp );
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Having an alias in the configuration should make require() exposed AFAIK. Did you have a look at the generated 'public-dev/js/app.dev.js' file? Also, just to make sure, you do include public-dev/js/app.dev.js correctly in your index.html?

Comment: @AmitayDobo I thought the same, but I'm running into the very same issue of require not being defined globally

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters, the src attribute in your grunt file doesn't need to reference all of the files in your application. It only needs an entry point. So normally I have something similar to your anonymous self executing function in an index.js file, and set my src configuration option to `["./index.js"]`. When browserify looks at that file, it will check for calls to require and grab all of the required dependencies.

That said, browserify will generate a file with an internal definition of require. The require function is not globally available on the page, nor are the dependencies that you include with require. You can use them in your application, but that doesn't make them available in the page. So if you are getting a Backbone is not defined error, the first thing I would check is that you have installed backbone via npm (`npm install backbone --save`).

Once everything is set up you should just have to include your compiled script on the page, and let your anonymous self executing function (which should now be in a file that grunt-browserify is processing) do the work to kick off your application.